# Can I automate emailing of critical errors with systemd journal?

Tags: linux, logging, fedora, rsyslog, journal

Fedora OS introduces `journalctl` as the new way to log error messages. I learn about this recently when I performed an upgrade. `var/log/messages` and many other log files are now combined into a `.journal` file within the `var/log/journal` directory.

I have a custom log that was created specially to log critical errors using the old `rsyslog`:

```
*.crit  /var/log/critical/log
```

This file will be emailed to me and rotated every hour using a cron job as long as there is an error. Now, how would this be done using `journalctl`? The options in `journald.conf` seems pretty [limited](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html). Do I still require `rsyslog` to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This command produces a similar output

```
journalctl --since="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d '1 hour ago')" --priority=crit --quiet
```

Comment: Let me guess. You are suggesting that I run the above command with cron?

Comment: Yeah, if you put it directly in cron, note that the '%' have special significance in cron, replace with '%%'.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. I read through the man page, but the command you wrote within `--since` is not documented anywhere. Can you elaborate further what the `$` sign and `-d` does? Thanks.

Comment: On my Fedora Server 25 system I was able to avoid running "date". This is my cron job: `@hourly journalctl --since="1 hour ago" --priority=warning --quiet`

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I've written a small program, journal-brief, to give a briefing of journal messages since the last time it was run.

https://github.com/twaugh/journal-brief

If you run it from cron (e.g. journal-brief -p err) you'll be mailed its output.

It bookmarks where it was up to by remembering the journal cursor, so it won't send duplicate log entries.

Comment: This tool is fabulous, and I've just sent a PR to add support for sending the output via email so that there is no need to run it through 'cron' or a similar tool.